Transfering attribute from line layer to polygon layer by their overlay in QGIS
I have a polygon layer that represents sub-catchments and a line layer that represents a stream network. There is exactly one feature in the line layer for each polygon. I have used v.rast.stats to calculate the average slope for each line feature.
Now I would like to transfer this attribute to the polygon layer. In other words, the polygon layer should receive information about the average flow gradient in each feature. How can this be done?
Here is a screenshot:

The red lines are the line layer, the white lines are the boundaries of the polygons and in the background is the slope grid.

Look at a spatial join.

I did it with Join attributes by location. For join to features I used the Polygon layer, features they (geometric predicate) intersect, by comparing to the Line Layer.
